# SQL help! How to create a new column that shows the time duration between two different periods

Tags: mysql, sql, case, datediff

In the new data set I create two new columns, Start_time and End_time. I want to also create a column that shows the difference between these two times. This is my code:

```
SELECT   b.company, 
     b.NAME, 
     Max( 
     CASE 
              WHEN description = 'Green' THEN final_value 
     END) AS 'Start_Time', 
     Max( 
     CASE 
              WHEN description = 'Red' THEN final_value 
     END) AS 'End_Time', 
     cast(datediff(n, 
       CASE('End_Time' as datetime), 
     CASE('Start_Time' AS datetime)) AS float) / 60 AS time_duration 
FROM     mydata a 
JOIN     ref_val b 
ON       a.ref_res = b.ref_res 
WHERE    b.company = 'abc' 
GROUP BY b.company , 
     b.NAME
```

When I run this code I get an error saying End_Time can not be bound. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You can't use a column alias as a reference in the select. You can't use column aliases like that in many places actually. Try simply copying and pasting the code for your Start_Time and End_Time calculations and put it inside your DATEDIFF. Right now, you are trying to cast the string literal 'End_Time' to datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use sub-query to use the alias you created also you cannot cast the value in mysql using float type.

```
SELECT *, CAST(DATEDIFF(n, CAST(End_Time AS datetime), CAST(Start_Time AS datetime)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / 60 AS Time_Duration
  FROM (SELECT  B.COMPANY
               ,B.NAME
               ,MAX(case when DESCRIPTION = 'Green' then Final_Value end) as Start_Time
               ,MAX(case when DESCRIPTION = 'Red' then Final_Value end) as End_Time
          FROM mydata a
          JOIN ref_val B 
            ON A.ref_res = B.ref_res    
         WHERE B.COMPANY = 'abc'
         GROUP BY  B.COMPANY
                  ,B.NAME
        ) C
```